Ubuntu 24.04 system icons disappeared after installing and uninstalling kubuntu-desktop package
After installing kubuntu-desktop to do a test, some icons (tray and settings app) have been lost and there's no way to recover them. I've tried reinstalling almost every Ubuntu Desktop package and it's impossible.
It's frustrating how even the simplest thing becomes so complicated.
Is there any way to recover the icons?


